# Prompt algorithm to search for key points on image

Tags: image, algorithm

I have a scanned image with the key points. 
When scanning the image can be shifted. 
I want to crop the image on the key points. 
Prompt, please search algorithm points.

The scanned image
[image: The scanned image]
<sub>(source: [cs618230.vk.me](http://cs618230.vk.me/v618230867/7d64/Wch0m4Ie7PQ.jpg))</sub>

Cropping
[image: Cropping]
<sub>(source: [cs618230.vk.me](http://cs618230.vk.me/v618230867/7d6b/quEnLqz8OiQ.jpg))</sub>

Сropped image
[image: Сropped image]
<sub>(source: [cs618230.vk.me](http://cs618230.vk.me/v618230867/7d72/6OHqb_HIsI0.jpg))</sub>

Comment: what is the programe language you going to use?

Comment: programe language - C#

Comment: does it correctly cropped in image named cropped image which you have attached ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[Viola Jones Object Detection framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework)** to find these key points.

Even though the algorithm is mostly used for face detection, the algorithm is adapted to general objects, including your key points.

The idea is to use [supervised machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) in order to train the framework, that will later be able to find the key points in all pictures.

The algorithm itself, after creating the classifier, is using a sliding window, and classifying all pictures encountered in this sliding window - are they the desired objects (key points in your example) or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hough Transform - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

Answer (score 0):

I used cross-correlation function. It work.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation